# Msvc command compilation errror with glad library

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-c++, glfw, glad

I am using glfw3 and glad library.  The problem is that my cl.exe compiler isn't compiling the way I want it to .

Here is my main.cpp:

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "C:\msvc64\include\GLFW\glfw3.h"
#include "C:\msvc64\include\GLFW\glfw3native.h"
#include "C:\msvc64\include\glad\gl.h"


void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", description);
}

static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    // Key call backs.
}

void drawSquare() {
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2f(0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex2f(-0.5, 0.5);
    glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5);
    glVertex2f(0.5, -0.5);
    glEnd();
}

int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hInstPrev, PSTR cmdline, int cmdshow) {
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        return MessageBox(NULL, L"failed to initialize glfw", L"Error", 0);
    };

    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "My Title", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        return MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to create window", L"Error", 0);
    };

    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

    // Make the OpenGL context current
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    int width, height;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    double time = glfwGetTime();

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        // Main loop
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        drawSquare();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

        // Check if the user attempted to close the window
        if (glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
            break; // Exit the loop
        }

        // Other application logic goes here
    }

    // Clean up and terminate GLFW
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

those libraries you see (msvc64) are libraries I made so that I can use cl.exe easier. I do not think the problem is with glfw3 since when I run the compilation with glfw3 only it compiles like a charm.

The command line code I used was:

```
CL.exe /c /IC:\msvc64\include\GLFW /IC:\msvc64\include\ /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /sdl /O2 /Oi /GL /D NDEBUG /D _CONSOLE /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /permissive- /Fo"C:\Users\name\Desktop\GameMake\\" /Fd"C:\Users\name\Desktop\GameMake\vc143.pdb" /external:W3 /Gd /TP /FC /errorReport:prompt main.cpp "C:\msvc64\src\gl.c"
main.cpp
gl.c
C:\msvc64\src\gl.c(2302,5): warning C4551: function call missing argument list.
```

I cant use the linking (link.exe) to convert this to .exe as I would need to use the .obj and other files created from cl.exe

```
link.exe /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /OUT:"C:\Users\name\Desktop\GameMake\game.exe" /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:C:\msvc64\lib glfw3.lib OpenGL32.lib User32.lib gdi32.lib shell32.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\Users\name\Desktop\GameMake\game.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /LTCG:incremental /LTCGOUT:"C:\Users\name\Desktop\GameMake\game.iobj" /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"C:\Users\las-nawzad\Desktop\GameMake\game.lib" 
/MACHINE:X64 C:\Users\las-nawzad\Desktop\GameMake\main.obj
```

I was expecting the code to compile without any difficulties and for me to convert the .cpp to an exe code.

I tried looking at the gl.c (from glad/src) and the line 2302 column 5 which I see `GLAD_UNUSED(glad_gl_has_extension);`
and I am stumped because I do not know why that line would be wrong. I also have tried downloading the glad library from https://gen.glad.sh/generated/tmpy5zlowskglad/ but I still get the same result.

Comment: Did you read [Getting Started](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick.html), [Compiling GLFW](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/compile_guide.html) and [Building applications](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html) pages?

Comment: The getting started page was the original thing I had to learn how to code in glfw. I noticed that there was a glad.h and did more research and installed it as I said previously, the getting started did not specify how to install glad (At least from what I read) the compiling glfw was only for glfw not glad. Thank you for trying though.

Comment: `#include "C:\msvc64\src\gl.c"` is an odd thing to do. Normally you never ever include a source file.

Comment: I expect the error happens because in `gl.c` it does not know what `GLAD_UNUSED` is.

Comment: Yes. I tried to do a source file because I thought it would work with the compiler, however, I removed it from the code and I still got the same error. I don't think it is the including of the source file.

Comment: Then how do I make gl.c understand GLAD_UNUSED. I am sorry if that sounded like a stupid question but I am new and the gl.c was from the glad source

Comment: I even tried defining it in my main.cpp by doing #ifndef GLAD_UNUSED
#define GLAD_UNUSED
#endif however I get a macro error and the same error still occurs

Comment: CL.exe /c /IC:\msvc64\include\GLFW /IC:\msvc64\include\ /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /sdl /O2 /Oi /GL /D NDEBUG /D _CONSOLE /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /permissive- /Fo"C:\Users\name\Desktop\GameMake\\" /Fd"C:\Users\name\Desktop\GameMake\vc143.pdb" /external:W3 /Gd /TP /FC /errorReport:prompt main.cpp "C:\msvc64\src\gl.c"
main.cpp
C:\msvc64\include\glad\gl.h(118,1): warning C4005: 'GLAD_UNUSED': macro redefinition
C:\Users\name\Desktop\GameMake\main.cpp(3,1): note: see previous definition of 'GLAD_UNUSED'
gl.c

Comment: C:\msvc64\src\gl.c(2302,5): warning C4551: function call missing argument list

Comment: `#include "C:\msvc64\src\gl.c"` Never do that.

Comment: The glad header must be included before glfw3. https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/build_guide.html#:~:text=If%20you%20are%20using%20an,of%20the%20default%20OpenGL%20header.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have solved the opengl problem. The problem was in the cl I should have also included the glad folder and KHR folder which was the problem then if you do that you will notice for the linking you would get an error thats because the cl would also make a glad.obj which you have to combine main.obj with glad.obj to make the working .exe

not only that you require gl.c, gl.h, glad.h and glad.c which can be downloaded from the glad generator. you would include gl.h (glad/include/gl.h) to the code and the compile it with glad.c   (I dont know if gl.c and glad.h are necessary ).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).